# Can't open behance.net from phantomjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I would like to open behance.net via phantomjs.

Unfortunately, Behance didn't open. It looks like error page from behance.

Here is my code:

```
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36';

page.open( "https://www.behance.net/gallery/51611361/Sound-Logo-Free-Download", function( status )
{
    if(status === "success")
    {

        page.injectJs('jquery.js');

        var result = page.evaluate(function()
        {
            console.log( $("body").html() );
            return 0
        });
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

**UPD**

I rendered the page to jpeg, and it is just a black screen.

**UPD 2. SOLUTION**

Behance used 3 iframe inside the page, so onLoadFinished invokes 3 times. But when you call

```
open("url", function(){
    console.log('loaded'); // only one
})
```

Solution:
write `onLoadFinished` function outside `open` function

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(status)
{
    console.log('loaded'); // three times. On three the page is loaded
}
```

Comment: please, show also the error

Comment: There is many code. Some div's

Comment: <h1 id="we-noticed">We notice you are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer.</h1>
<h2 id="browser-not-supported">This version is not supported by Behance.</h2>

Comment: Use a custom user agent, like Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I already checked user agent and it is Safari, like a default browser

Comment: Try Chrome then.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I tried it and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

> We notice you are using an outdated version of
>   Internet Explorer. This version is
>   not supported by Behance.

This site doesn't like old IE versions (and I won't blame it).

Use a custom user userAgent: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html

This will prevent Phantom to request the page as Internet Explorer, and the site will accept to load.

Comment: i tried this approach, it didn't help.
example: 
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36';

Comment: @seliseev Update your code to show **how** you've used this useragent.